# How can I do if I want to press a cell from a tableview that opens a collectionview in code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is my storyboard
[image]

And here is the code from the last tableview
[image]

Comment: In storyboard have you set the collection view class for its view controller ?

Comment: Yes. All controllers have their own classes

Comment: you can navigate to collectionView controller on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: your having an error when you navigate with segue and it might be that you connected collectionView wrong in your view controller that manager collection view or you might be having two connections for your collection view

Comment: Oh that was a test. I wanted to see if my Collection View works without anything else so that's why i made it Initial View Controller. But it didn't work even before that when a table view controller was the initial view controller. So the problem it's not there

Comment: Please replace your images with code. It is impossible to search images...

Comment: And if i use didSelectRowAtIndexPath it throws me this : "Unknown class CollectionViewController in Interface Builder file."

Answer (score 0):

you should implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifierHereFromStoryboard", sender: yourSender or nil ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PatientDetailTableViewController, you can implement func of tableview delegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let collectionView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CollectionViewController") as! CollectionViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(collectionView, animated: true)
}
```

and in your storyboard, remember fill Storyboard ID: "CollectionViewController"